# Indexing data.frames using arrays of TRUEs and FALSEs

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, shapes, logical-operators

I'm having some trouble indexing data.frames in R. I'm an R beginner. I have a `data.frame` called `d` which has 35512 columns and 77 rows. I have a list called `rd` which contains 35512 elements. I'd like all the columns of `d` which correspond to the items in `rd` less than 100. Here's what I'm doing:

```
# just to prove I'm not crazy
> length(colnames(d))
[1] 35512
> length(rownames(d))
[1] 77
> length(rd)
[1] 35512
# find all the elements of rd less than 100 (+ unnecessary faffing?)
> i <- unlist(rd<100)
> names(i) <- NULL
# try to extract all the elements of d corresponding to rd < 100
> d <- d[,i]
Error in `[.data.frame`(d, , i) : undefined columns selected
```

I don't really want to be doing the `unlist` and `names(i) <- NULL` stuff but I'm getting seriously paranoid. Can anyone help with what the hell this error message means?

In case it helps, the `rd` variable is created using the following:

```
rd = lapply(lapply(d, range), diff)
```

Which hopefully tells me the difference in the range of each column of `d`.

P.S. bonus awesomeness for anyone who can tell me a command to find the shape of a data.frame other than querying the length of its row and column names.

Edit: Here's what `rd` looks like:

```
> rd[1:3]
$`10338001`
[1] 7198.886

$`10338003`
[1] 4748.963

$`10338004`
[1] 3173.046
```

and when I've done my faffing, `i` looks like this:

```
> i[7:10]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: What is the length of i?  Confirm that this is true: `length(i) == ncol(d)`.  Also, check if you have any NA's in i.  `any(is.na(i))`  Lastly, check `is.logical(i)`.

Comment: Argh! `any(is.na(i))` returns `TRUE`. Thanks for this clue!

Comment: Why do you have such a wide data.frame? Are you sure you don't want a long data.frame instead? Or if everything's numeric, just a matrix? Internally, data.frames are lists of column vectors, so very wide dfs are not very efficient to manipulate.

Comment: Hi Harlan - my data.frame has simply ended up this way after days of my inexpert hacking. I didn't know about the internal representation, and I guess I'm used to a row-centric representation from Python! Will transpose... It's a data.frame not a matrix as there were factors in there until i decided to be interested in the range of each column. Essentially there's no design here; i just follow chalk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
d[,rd < 100]
```

Here's a self-contained example:

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(1:100, ncol=10))
rd <- as.list(1:10)
d[,rd < 5]
```

To get the shape of a dataframe, use `nrow` and `ncol`.

*Edit:*

Based on your response to my `NA` question, it sounds like you have non-logical values in your index that result from missing values in your list.  The best thing to do is to first decide how you want to treat a missing value.  Then deal with them using the `is.na` function (here I extend my example from above):

```
rd[[3]] <- NA
d[,rd < 5]
# => Error in `[.data.frame`(d, , rd < 5) : undefined columns selected
```

To deal with this, I will set that NA value to 0 (which means that it the respective column will be included in the final data.frame):

```
rd[is.na(rd)] <- 0
d[,rd < 5]
```

You need to decide for yourself what to do with the `NA` values.

Comment: yep! That's what I tried first. I got the same error. That's when I started unlisting and removing the names and such. 
    > d[,rd < 100]
    Error in `[.data.frame`(d, , rd < 100) : undefined columns selected

Comment: Please provide a small sample of the data for rd.

Answer (score 1):

For the bonus Q, you get "shape" of a data frame or matrix using the "**dim**" command.

```
A = matrix( ceiling(10*runif(40)), nrow=8)
colnames(A) = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
df = data.frame(A)
b = ceiling(100*runif(5))

ndx = b < 50          
result = df[,ndx]     # just the columns of df corresponding to b < 50
```

Comment: thanks for the 'dim' command! I think i need to purchase some yellow springer